# Merge two dataframes based on time columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Note:** I asked a similar question with the same data earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238564/pandas-combine-two-dataframes-based-on-time-difference), but now I'm trying to merge the dataframes in a different way.

I have two data frames that stores different types of medical information of patients. The common elements of both the data frames are the encounter ID (`hadm_id`), the time the information was recorded (`(n|c)e_charttime`).

One data frame (`ds`) contains structured information and the other data frame (`dn`) contains a column with a clinical note recorded at a specified time for an encounter. Both these data frames contain multiple encounters, but the common element is the encounter ID (`hadm_id`).

Here are examples of the data frames:

```
ds
    hadm_id ce_charttime    hr  sbp dbp
0   140694  2121-08-12 19:00:00 67.0    102.0   75.0
1   140694  2121-08-12 19:45:00 68.0    135.0   68.0
2   140694  2121-08-12 20:00:00 70.0    153.0   94.0
3   171544  2153-09-06 14:11:00 80.0    114.0   50.0
4   171544  2153-09-06 17:30:00 80.0    114.0   50.0
5   171544  2153-09-06 17:35:00 80.0    114.0   50.0
6   171544  2153-09-06 17:40:00 76.0    115.0   51.0
7   171544  2153-09-06 17:45:00 79.0    117.0   53.0
```

```
dn
    hadm_id ne_charttime    note
0   140694  2121-08-10 20:32:00 some text1
1   140694  2121-08-11 12:57:00 some text2
2   140694  2121-08-11 15:18:00 some text3
3   171544  2153-09-05 15:09:00 some text4
4   171544  2153-09-05 17:43:00 some text5
5   171544  2153-09-06 10:36:00 some text6
6   171544  2153-09-06 15:55:00 some text7
7   171544  2153-09-06 17:12:00 some text8
```

The actuall data consists of nearly 10,000 encounters and over 250,000 rows of structured data and 50,000 rows of clinical notes.

I want to merge them according to the time that information was charted. For example, if you take a single encounter from both dataframes and sort them according to the charttime, I want all the information in the resulting dataframe, with `NaN`s for missing values. For example, if the above two dataframes were the input, my resulting dataframe would look like:

```
final
    hadm_id charttime   ce_charttime    hr  sbp dbp ne_charttime    note
0   140694  2121-08-10 20:32:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2121-08-10 20:32:00 some text1
1   140694  2121-08-11 12:57:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2121-08-11 12:57:00 some text2
2   140694  2121-08-11 15:18:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2121-08-11 15:18:00 some text3
3   140694  2121-08-12 19:00:00 2121-08-12 19:00:00 67.0    102.0   75.0    NaT NaN
4   140694  2121-08-12 19:45:00 2121-08-12 19:45:00 68.0    135.0   68.0    NaT NaN
5   140694  2121-08-12 20:00:00 2121-08-12 20:00:00 70.0    153.0   94.0    NaT NaN
6   171544  2153-09-05 15:09:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2153-09-05 15:09:00 some text4
7   171544  2153-09-05 17:43:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2153-09-05 17:43:00 some text5
8   171544  2153-09-06 10:36:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2153-09-06 10:36:00 some text6
9   171544  2153-09-06 14:11:00 2153-09-06 14:11:00 80.0    114.0   50.0    NaT NaN
10  171544  2153-09-06 15:55:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2153-09-06 15:55:00 some text7
11  171544  2153-09-06 17:12:00 NaT NaN NaN NaN 2153-09-06 17:12:00 some text8
12  171544  2153-09-06 17:30:00 2153-09-06 17:30:00 80.0    114.0   50.0    NaT NaN
13  171544  2153-09-06 17:35:00 2153-09-06 17:35:00 80.0    114.0   50.0    NaT NaN
14  171544  2153-09-06 17:40:00 2153-09-06 17:40:00 76.0    115.0   51.0    NaT NaN
15  171544  2153-09-06 17:45:00 2153-09-06 17:45:00 76.0    117.0   53.0    NaT NaN
```

I actually manually typed this resulting dataframe and I would like a way to produce this with pandas. Eventually, I will drop `ce_charttime` and `ne_charttime` and retain only the newly created `charttime` column and fill in the missing values appropriately later. Any help is appreciated, please let me know if additional info is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Eventually, I will drop `ce_charttime` and `ne_charttime` and retain only the newly created `charttime`

You could do that *before* joining both dataframes, then the pandas `concat` function could be used to append them into a single one.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def parse_datetime(strftime):
    datetime.strptime(strftime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# here I'm assuming both dataframes share a column `charttime` on the same axis
data1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', parse_dates=True, date_parser=parse_datetime)
data2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', parse_dates=True, date_parser=parse_datetime)

print(data1.head(10), end='\n\n')
print(data2.head(10), end='\n\n')

data = pd.concat([data1, data2],  axis=0, sort=True)
data.sort_values(by=['charttime'], inplace=True)
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(data.head(20))
```

Here's the output of the code above:

```
   hadm_id            charttime    hr    sbp   dbp
0   140694  2121-08-12 19:00:00  67.0  102.0  75.0
1   140694  2121-08-12 19:45:00  68.0  135.0  68.0
2   140694  2121-08-12 20:00:00  70.0  153.0  94.0
3   171544  2153-09-06 14:11:00  80.0  114.0  50.0
4   171544  2153-09-06 17:30:00  80.0  114.0  50.0
5   171544  2153-09-06 17:35:00  80.0  114.0  50.0
6   171544  2153-09-06 17:40:00  76.0  115.0  51.0
7   171544  2153-09-06 17:45:00  79.0  117.0  53.0

   hadm_id            charttime        note
0   140694  2121-08-10 20:32:00  some text1
1   140694  2121-08-11 12:57:00  some text2
2   140694  2121-08-11 15:18:00  some text3
3   171544  2153-09-05 15:09:00  some text4
4   171544  2153-09-05 17:43:00  some text5
5   171544  2153-09-06 10:36:00  some text6
6   171544  2153-09-06 15:55:00  some text7
7   171544  2153-09-06 17:12:00  some text8

              charttime   dbp  hadm_id    hr        note    sbp
0   2121-08-10 20:32:00   NaN   140694   NaN  some text1    NaN
1   2121-08-11 12:57:00   NaN   140694   NaN  some text2    NaN
2   2121-08-11 15:18:00   NaN   140694   NaN  some text3    NaN
3   2121-08-12 19:00:00  75.0   140694  67.0         NaN  102.0
4   2121-08-12 19:45:00  68.0   140694  68.0         NaN  135.0
5   2121-08-12 20:00:00  94.0   140694  70.0         NaN  153.0
6   2153-09-05 15:09:00   NaN   171544   NaN  some text4    NaN
7   2153-09-05 17:43:00   NaN   171544   NaN  some text5    NaN
8   2153-09-06 10:36:00   NaN   171544   NaN  some text6    NaN
9   2153-09-06 14:11:00  50.0   171544  80.0         NaN  114.0
10  2153-09-06 15:55:00   NaN   171544   NaN  some text7    NaN
11  2153-09-06 17:12:00   NaN   171544   NaN  some text8    NaN
12  2153-09-06 17:30:00  50.0   171544  80.0         NaN  114.0
13  2153-09-06 17:35:00  50.0   171544  80.0         NaN  114.0
14  2153-09-06 17:40:00  51.0   171544  76.0         NaN  115.0
15  2153-09-06 17:45:00  53.0   171544  79.0         NaN  117.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Couple of questions: 1) I noticed that there is no groupby `hadm_id` in this code. Will all operations get correctly applied per encounter? Because there might be encounters that happened at the same time but with different `hadm_id`. 2) What would happen if there were both types of data taken at the same time?